# ILNumerics axis configuration

Tags: c#, .net, ilnumerics

Need your advice!

I use TickCreationFunc and LabelTransformFunc to show timeline on XAxis

Something like this:

```cs
var plotCube = new ILPlotCube(tag, true);

List<Tuple<double, string>> ticks = null;

plotCube.Axes.XAxis.Ticks.TickCreationFunc = (min, max, qty) =>
{
    ticks = AxisHelper.CreateUnixDateTicks(min, max, qty).ToList();

    return ticks.Select(x => (float)x.Item1).ToList();
};

plotCube.Axes.XAxis.Ticks.LabelTransformFunc = (ind, val) =>
{
    if (ticks != null)
        return ticks[ind].Item2;
    else
        return null;
};

plotCube.Axes.XAxis.ScaleLabel.Visible = false; //does not help
```

The result is quite good however I could not find a way to remove the scale label

[image: Timeline axis]

Two side questions:

1) VS shows warning *'ILNumerics.Drawing.Plotting.ILTickCollection.TickCreationFunc' is obsolete: '"Use TickCreationFuncEx instead!"'*. However TickCreationFuncEx is never called.

2) Is there a way to tell ILNumerics not to abbreviate tick numbers?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

1. This warning is important. The scale label should go away if you use the new `TickCreationFuncEx`. The interface is very similar. But your function must return `IEnumerable<ILTick>`:

   ```
   var plotCube = ilPanel1.Scene.First<ILPlotCube>();

   List<Tuple<double, string>> ticks = null;

   plotCube.Axes.XAxis.Ticks.TickCreationFuncEx = 
       (float min, float max, int qty, ILAxis axis, AxisScale scale) => {
           ticks = CreateUnixDateTicks(min, max, qty).ToList();

           return // return IEnumerable<ILTick> here!
   };
   // you should not need this
   //plotCube.Axes.XAxis.ScaleLabel.Visible = false;
   ```
2. One cannot disable abbreviation completely. But you can specify the number of digits to show. Until 4.7 (due to a bug) you will have to use this:

   ```
   ilPanel1.SceneSyncRoot.First<ILPlotCube>().Axes.XAxis.Ticks.MaxNumberDigitsShowFull = 10;
   ```

   From version 4.8 you will not need `SceneSyncRoot` anymore and can go more straight:

   ```
   ilPanel1.Scene.First<ILPlotCube>().Axes.XAxis.Ticks.MaxNumberDigitsShowFull = 10; 
   // or in your case just 
   plotcube.Axes.XAxis.Ticks.MaxNumberDigitsShowFull = 10;
   ```

Note: used XAxis in the code and not YAxis acc. to your example

Comment: Thanks Haymo, I tried the solution with TickCreationFuncEx. The problem there is that it never get called. Please advise what could be wrong.

Comment: You may have to set the deprecated version to null? Oherwise it takes precedence.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: If I set them to null I am getting 'null reference exception'.

I am using Nuget version which is 3.3.3 I believe.

Comment: ilPanel1.SceneSyncRoot.First<ILPlotCube>().Axes.XAxis.Ticks.MaxNumberDigitsShowFull = 10; from time to time fails with exception 'sequence contains no elements' seems like a race condition ):

Comment: Yes, I should! Is Nuget version abandoned? Any plans to update it?